# Question in proof of a corollary of Hilbert Nullstellansatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I have been reading commutative algebra from lecture notes and I have some questions in a proof of a corollary of Hilbert Nullstellansatz.

> Let R be a finitely generated k-algebra. Then for an ideal $I \subseteq R$,  $\sqrt{I} =\cap M$, where M are maximal ideals containing I.

Proof: Clearly $\sqrt{I} \subseteq RHS$( **Can you please explain why?**) Let $f\notin \sqrt{I} => f^n \notin I $ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $S= ${$f^n : n=0,1,2,...$} => $S\cap I =\phi$ , Consider the ideal $S^{-1} P $, maximal in $S^{-1} R$ , where P is a prime ideal in R. ( **Can you please explain why $S^{-1} P$ is maximal?**) Claim: P is maximal ideal in R. R/P is a finite extension of K and $S^{-1} R / S^{-1} P$ is a finitely generated K -algebra . So, using weak form of nullstellansatz , $S^{-1} R / S^{-1} P$ is a finite extension of K. So, $S^{-1}R / S^{-1} P$ is a finite extension over R/P and hence R/P is a field and P is maximal.( **Can you please tell how extension being finite implies that R/P is a field?**)=> P is maximal ideal with $f\notin P $ which implies that $\cap M \subseteq \sqrt{I}$.( **Can you please tell how does P is maximal implies that $f\notin P$ and how does it implies that $\cap M \subseteq \sqrt{I}$?**)

> I will grant a bounty of 50 to an answer that explains 3 or more questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it Nullstellansatz (a type of Ansatz) or Nullstellensatz (theorem about Nullstellen)??  It seems math.se has 15 posts about "Nullstellansatz"...

Comment: @GEdgar I have raised the flag. Thanks for telling.

Comment: Actually, it is Hilbert's "Nullstellensatz", effectively translating to "Theorem of Zeroes" (Nullstelle = Zero of a function).

Answer (score 1):

1. Recall that maximal ideals are prime and thus radical. Thus, if $I \subseteq M$ for some maximal ideal $M$, then also $\sqrt{I} \subseteq M$.
2. The ideals of $S^{-1} R$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of $R$ that intersect $S$ trivially (given by $I \mapsto S^{-1}I$ and $J \mapsto R \cap J$). In particular, every ideal $J \subseteq S^{-1}R$ satisfies $J = S^{-1}(R \cap J)$. If $J$ is maximal, then it is prime and then also $R \cap J$ is prime in $R$.
3. If $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra which is an integral domain (like $R/P$), then $A$ is a field: for every non-zero $a \in A$ the multiplication map $x \mapsto ax$ is an injective $k$-linear transformation from a finite dimensional vector space into itself and thus it is also surjective and we find $b \in A$ with $ab = 1$.
4. $f$ is invertible in $S^{-1}R$ and thus not contained in any proper ideal, in particular not in $S^{-1}P$ and consequently not in $P$, which we have shown is maximal. In particular, we take $S^{-1}P$ a maximal ideal containing $S^{-1}I$ (I believe this should have been done in the first place), then $P$ turns out to be a maximal ideal containing $I$ which does not contain $f$. Thus, $f$ is not contained in the intersection of maximal ideals containing $I$.

Comment: I will give this bounty to you.

Comment: In 2 I am not able to understand how you wrote: in particular every ideal $J\subseteq S^{-1} R$ satisfies  $J= S^{-1} (R\cap J)$?

Comment: You have a one-to-one correspondence between ideals of $R$ intersecting $S$ trivially and the ideals of $S^{-1}R$. The maps $I \mapsto S^{-1} I$ and $J \mapsto R \cap J$ define bijections between these sets of ideals which are inverse to one another. In particular, their composition yields the identity, thus $J = S^{-1} (R \cap J)$. You can show this identity also directly: if $r/s \in J$, then $r = s  \cdot r/s \in J \cap R$ and so r/s \in S^{-1}(J \cap R). If $r \in R \cap J$ and $s \in S$, then $r/s = 1/s \cdot r \in J$.